# Why can assignment in a 'for' loop change an inner list when iterating over 2-dimensional lists, but not change elements in a flat list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

For the following two codes, please explain why one works and the other does not.

Code 1:

```
y = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4']]
for x in y:
    x[0] = x[0] + '9'

print(y)
```

Result: `[['19', '2'], ['39', '4']]`

Code 2:

```
y = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
for x in y:
    x = x + '9'

print(y)
```

Result: `['1', '2', '3', '4']`

Why does the result of code 1 have a 9 at the end, and the result of code 2 does not have a 9 at the end?

Answer (score 1):

In the first code snippet, you have a list of list's and in the second code snippet you gave, you have a list of strings. Python's built in `list` is **mutable**. This means that **mutating** the list will change it's original entries as in the first code snippet. Hence, the nines are appended in the result of the first snippet. In the, second snippet, you tried modifying each element in the array, however since strings in python are **immutable** changing the string won't change the original entries in the array. But rather creates a new string, which is unused until the end of the loop. As a result, the array in the second example is left untouched.

Comment: I don't think it's because it's a string. Even if the elements of the list are integers, it doesn't change.

Comment: Whether or not the elements are strings does not matter. In the first example you are *mutating* (modifying) lists. In the second example, the statement `for x in y: x = x + '9'` does not do anything useful: it just changes the local variable `x`, but it *does not* modify the list `y`.

Comment: Yes, you're exactly right. It's not because it's a string (I said string because it's used in your example). It's because the datatype that you are 'attempting' to modify is immutable. So, what python will do is create a new variable, the result of the operation `x + '9'` and save it into `x`, but it won't modify the original list. The same thing will happen, when you try it on tuples and integers for example. I hope that helps.